# Python and MQTT optimization

Tags: python, mqtt

I have the following code that I've been asked to 'tidy up'. At the moment I think its not optimal, so I'd like some advice on how to make it so please.

I have 4 voltages received as MQTT messages (power1,power2 etc.), corresponding to 4 different measuring stations, each of which is a value I append to a new array 'power'. If the values lie between 'Vtrig' and 'Vlow', they are appended to another array 'flags', whose length, when exceeding a certain value (Flag_length), triggers a flag I can send out as an MQTT message, so that way if I get multiple values outside of the required range I'm notified. Otherwise, the array is emptied and we start again.

Here's what I wrote so far:

```
import smbus
import time
import csv
from datetime import datetime

import paho.mqtt.client as paho
 
MQTT_HOST = '10.10.20.122'
MQTT_PORT = 1883
MQTT_CLIENT_ID = 'lowerStation'
TOPIC = 'pwrTest/testData'
TOPIC_TOM = 'pwrTest/Error'
TOPICeval = 'pwrTest/testEval'
Vtrig = 12
Vlow = 0.1
Flag_length = 7

flags0=[]
flags1=[]
flags2=[]
flags3=[]
 
client = paho.Client(MQTT_CLIENT_ID)
 
client.connect(MQTT_HOST, MQTT_PORT)

# Serial numbers to Volito connected to measureing station, station 1 to 4
SN = [109, 78, 86, 60]

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc==0:
        print('connected')
    else:
        print('Bad connection code =', rc)
        
broker = '10.10.20.122'
client.connect(broker)  #connect to broker
client.on_connect = on_connect #bind call back function
print('Connecting to broker', broker)
```

**But this is really the relevant part.**

```
payload = str(power1) + "," + "Station1," + "SN" +str(SN[0])
    client.publish(TOPIC, payload)
    
    payload = str(power2) + "," + "Station2," + "SN" +str(SN[1])
    client.publish(TOPIC, payload)
    
    payload = str(power3) + "," + "Station3," + "SN" +str(SN[2])
    client.publish(TOPIC, payload)
    
    payload = str(power4) + "," + "Station4," + "SN" +str(SN[3])
    client.publish(TOPIC, payload)        
    
    power = []
    power.append(datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
    power.append(power1)
    power.append(power2)
    power.append(power3)
    power.append(power4)
    
    
    for x in power[1:2]:

        if x <Vtrig and x> Vlow:
            flags0.append(x)
        elif x>= Vtrig:
            flags0 = []
            

    if len(flags0) > Flag_length:
        payload = '5.0,' + "Station1," + "SN" +str(SN[0])
        flags0 = []
        client.publish(TOPICeval,payload)
        

    for x in power[2:3]:

        if x <Vtrig and x> Vlow:

            flags1.append(x)
        elif x>= Vtrig:
            flags1 = []
            

    if len(flags1) > Flag_length:
        payload = '5.0,' + "Station2," + "SN" +str(SN[1])
        flags1 = []
        client.publish(TOPICeval,payload)
        
    for x in power[3:4]:

        if x <Vtrig and x> Vlow:

            flags2.append(x)
        elif x>= Vtrig:
            flags2 = []


    if len(flags2) > Flag_length:
        
        payload ='5.0,' + "Station3," + "SN" +str(SN[2])
        flags2 = []
        client.publish(TOPICeval,payload)
        
    for x in power[4:5]:

        if x <Vtrig and x> Vlow:

            flags3.append(x)
        elif x>= Vtrig:
            flags3 = []
            

    if len(flags3) > Flag_length:
        payload ='5.0,' + "Station4," + "SN" +str(SN[3])
        flags3 = []
        client.publish(TOPICeval,payload)
        
    print('running')
    
    time.sleep(10)
```

As you can see I repeat the same code for each entry, is there a better way of writing this in a for loop?

Comment: One quick suggestion. You have a lot of slice operations that extract a single element (e.g. `power[2:3]`). Your code would be simpler if you just access the item directly `x = power[2]` (that way you don't need the loops). Changing that will also make it more obvious how to wrap all of these operations into a loop (as @JasonChia has done).

Answer (score 1):

Nice spot on simplification. I think you could do it like this.
Even better you should probably start using functions or debugging your code will be a nightmare in the future.

```
buffer = {} #a dict but probably other ways to do it
for index,value in enumerate(power):

    if value<Vtrig and value>Vlow: #your conditional checks
        buffer[index].append(value) #appends to the index of your power list
    elif value>= Vtrig: #conditional checks
        buffer[index] = [] #clearing the 'flag' list for index
    if len(buffer[index])> Flag_length:#your conditional check
        payload = '5.0, Station{}, SN{}'.format(index+1,SN[index]) 

#index from 0 so i think you want + 1 here for station and SN to equal the index
        buffer[index] = []    #clearing again 
        client.publish(TOPICeval,payload) #publishihing whatever you wanted
```

On another note, consider creating a class and creating functions. Would make your code much more readable.